# How to add new functions on button click

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a ngClass with condition in td as follows:

```
<tr>
    <td [ngClass]="{active: !show, inactive: show}"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This ngClass is activated on button click function as below:

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="show = !show">Play</button>
```

Now I have to add functions on this button click. How can add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `;` add multiple functions to the event.

```
(click)="show = !show; yourFunction()"
```

Comment: You can change that to (click) = “mymethod()”. And then implement “mymethod” in your component(.ts file).